# Adding New Column to Mapped Table using Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-interface

I have two entities as below:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}

public Class FourteenSteps
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string StepName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map these two into one entity which I am doing using Fluent API as below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
    .HasMany(c => c.FourteenSteps)
    .WithMany(d => d.Projects)
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("FourteenStepStatus")
    .MapLeftKey("ProjectId")
    .MapRightKey("FourteenStepsId"));
```

Now, the new table "FourteenStepStatus" got two fields called "ProjectId" and
   "FourteenStepsId".

I want to add one more field to "FourteenStepStatus" called "IsCompleted" which is 
   not part of the other two entities. How can I 
   do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want additional field in the junction table you cannot use it for many to many relation. You must instead introduce a new entity `FourteenStepStatus`, map all its columns and map two one-to-many relations: one between `Project` and `FourteenStepStatus` and second between `FourteenSteps` and `FourteenStepStatus`. Mapped many-to-many relation works only for scenarios where junction table contains only keys.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do have the FourteenStepStatus entity (below is the entity), what I am looking is to fill that table with mapped data whenever I create a new project record. How can I do that?                                                                       public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
        public int FourteenStepsId { get; set; }
        public virtual FourteenStep FourteenSteps { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of how to add the data. By adding the object to the context's FourteenStepStatus entity. Thank you.